# How to play Vimeo private files in Exo Player in Android

Tags: java, android, video, exoplayer2.x

```java
private void getVideo() {
        String uri = baseUrl +videoId;
        VimeoClient.getInstance().fetchNetworkContent(uri, new ModelCallback<Video>(Video.class) {
            @Override
            public void success(Video video) {

                ArrayList<VideoFile> videoFiles = video.files;
                if(videoFiles != null && !videoFiles.isEmpty()) {
                    VideoFile videoFile = videoFiles.get(0); // you could sort these files by size, fps, width/height
                    String link = videoFile.getLink();

                    initializePlayer(link);
                }
               // playVideoWebView(video.embed != null ? video.embed.html : null);
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(VimeoError error) {
                // voice the error
                Log.d("video_", "failure: "+error.getDeveloperMessage());
            }
        });
    }
```

**I got a link like this:  http://player.vimeo.com/external/{videoId}.sd.mp4?s={aKey}&profile_id={aProfileId}&oauth2_token_id={aToekn}**

```java
 private void initializePlayer(String url) {

        player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this);

        Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
        MediaSource mediaSource = buildMediaSource(uri);
        playerView.setPlayer(player);
        player.setPlayWhenReady(playWhenReady);
        player.seekTo(currentWindow, playbackPosition);
        player.prepare(mediaSource, false, false);


    }

private MediaSource buildMediaSource(Uri uri) { 
    DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(this, "exoplayer-codelab");
    return new ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory).createMediaSource(uri);
 }
```

Player screen is black and nothing is playing.

Comment: Could you add your function `buildMediaSource` to your post ? What is the version of exoplayer that you're using ? It seems it's a bit old as the new one use `SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(context).build()` to create the player

Comment: private MediaSource buildMediaSource(Uri uri) {
        DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory =
                new DefaultDataSourceFactory(this, "exoplayer-codelab");
        return new ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory)
                .createMediaSource(uri);
    }

Comment: problem is I'm getting a link that is mentioned above, and how extract this link to play in exoplayer

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code, have you first try with a standard link ? such as http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4

Comment: As far I found, I have pro account so that i can access files, and in files i get a link like above, but that link can not be play, may be there need some extractor. but also i found VimeoExtractor that also use a link line https://vimeo.com/video/videoId,  but i need to play above link that i mention above.

Comment: You didn't answer my question, is the exoplayer working with another url ?

Comment: yes exo player working fine with this url  https://vimeo.com/video/videoId using vimeoExtractor

Comment: Then your issue is laying in this url : `http://player.vimeo.com/external/{videoId}.sd.mp4?s={aKey}&profile_id={aProfileId}&oauth2_token_id={aToekn}`, since I can't use this URL I can't tell you exactly what it is, but your issue doesn't seems to come from your exoplayer implementation

Comment: No exo player is fine but I need to know how to play with that link, but thank u for your time